# Using Git when source directories are routinely deleted/overwritten

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to work out how to make Git work with the three other people I write code with in our office.  We develop custom applications for a myriad of different targets (in general, "targets" are embedded systems that won't run version control).

In an ideal world, we could create repositories in the individual source folders for each target, and be able to properly synchronize our work.  Code can be modified both offline as well as on a live system, but any time we modify code in a live system--which we would then want to transfer back to a dev machine for sharing/archiving--the development tool must completely delete the corresponding source folder on the dev machine and replace it with the directory from the target when we pull the modified code back.  That blasts away any repo-files in the directory whenever we want to backup changes made to a live system, which happens pretty much constantly.

Additionally, we have literally hundreds of different applications that need version control, which shouldn't all be stored on every development machine at the same time.  How can I make it possible to push/pull/clone individual applications without being able to store repository information in the individual source directories?

Comment: `Unfortunately, any time code is backed up [...] from the target.` I don't fully understand what you mean in that sentence. What does your backup system have to do with what's happening on the dev machine?

Comment: I had a diagram that shows it better, but I don't have the rep to post it.  Basically, the way writing to/copying back from the target platforms does a direct directory copy to/from the source directory.  So if we make changes to a live system, and want to bring those changes back to the dev machine, we copy into the source from the target

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have a problem with there being a .git file in the source folder, that you would want to copy to your target.

The simplest solution that I could think of is this:

- Create a git repository for each of your applications
- Put folder that should be uploaded to the target *inside* that repo.
  It could even be the only content at the root level of your git working copy.
- When making changes on the target:

  - Check, that your git working copy is clean (that you have committed or stashed away all changes you have made on your development machine) before you replace the folder. You might otherwise delete changes you have made on your local machine, but not committed yet.
  - Make sure that you have checked out the same commit on your local machine, that had been deployed to the system.
  - Do things the way you're doing them now. Delete that folder inside your working copy, but not the working copy itself.
  - Now `git status` and `git diff` will show you all files that changed and all changes that happened to them.
  - Commit them as needed.

---

This will help you put your source code under version control, without needing to put the repository itself on the embedded system.

You will get a full diff of everything that has changed on the system, but you will need to spend a lot of care, making sure you're editing the same revision on both sides.

---

Now as to storing all applications on every development machine:

Each of them should get their own git repo. If you have common code, that you use in multiple applications, [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) might be the right solution.

With three people working together in an office, you should have a central git server. Everybody can clone the project from there and pull/push changes to it. If you feel like you're not going to need a project again any time soon, you can delete it from your development computer. It's on the server (provided you have pushed all your changes).

Possible options include:

- Host yourself:

  - Stash
  - GitHub Enterprise
  - GitLab
- Service:

  - GitHub
  - Bitbucket